# Logback MDC print variables at runtime

Tags: logback, mdc

I was wondering if it is possible to print a previously added MDC value from a logger call?

example:

```
MDC.put("user","tom")

log.info("Hello %X{user}");
```

instead of adding it to the layout pattern.

The reason for this is that I call MDC elsewhere and I log at the end of my logic, but I want to conditionally log different values. I know a workaround might be different appenders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MDC is essentially a map, you can always use .get() to retrieve values previously stored in it:

```
MDC.put("user", "tom");

log.info("Hello, {}", MDC.get("user"));
```